# NullReferenceException in C# Dealing with XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm getting the NRE error that says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

From the following code:

```
  select new
                  {
                      ICAO = station.Element("icao").Value,
                  };
```

The entire script is:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=94107");

    var stations = from station in xmlDoc.Descendants("station")
                  select new
                  {
                      ICAO = station.Element("icao").Value,
                  };
    lblXml.Text = "";
    foreach (var station in stations)
    {
        lblXml.Text = lblXml.Text + "ICAO: " + station.ICAO + "<br />";
    }

    if (lblXml.Text == "")
        lblXml.Text = "No Results.";
    }
```

I don't understand why it isn't creating the station object and setting the ICAO value. Any ideas/tips for future XML and C# reference?

Comment: Why do you have a comma after the ICAO = station.Element("Icao").Value line? You're not getting multiple elements...

Comment: It doesn't hurt, and it may be that the real portion of code is much larger. If this is actually all that is done, you wouldn't need it within new{ ... } either, you could select the icao directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that only the airport stations have the icao element. This should work for you:

```
var stations = from airport in xmlDoc.Descendants("airport")
               from station in airport.Elements("station")
               select new
               {
                   ICAO = station.Element("icao").Value,
               };
```

You could instead add a where condition to get around the exception:

```
var stations = from station in xmlDoc.Descendants("station")
               where station.Element("icao") != null
               select new
               {
                   ICAO = station.Element("icao").Value,
               };
```

Also, you can pull a value like this to prevent an exception, though it will return numerous null records you may or may not want:

```
ICAO = (string)station.Element("icao")
```

You can do that for various other types, not only for strings.

Comment: Not to mention protecting against station.Element("icao") being null with either an extension method or a where clause.

Comment: The second route is probably better, since you're not imposing an artificial business rule that may or may not be true.

Comment: Yeah, a combination of both may be the ideal situation.

Answer (score 1):

The XML file in your sample returns some `station` elements with no `icao` descendant so sometimes `station.Element("icao")` will return null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `xmlDoc.Descendants("station")` is returning what you are expecting. You should examine the results here. This is why station.Element("icao") is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

That URL doesn't appear to be returning XML data, I suspect that's causing your node references to return nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var stations = from station in xmlDoc.Elements("station")
select new
{
    ICAO = station.Element("icao").Value,
};
```